# .Net method that mimics windows default file rename behavior

Tags: c#, .net, windows, file, rename

In Windows Explorer, if you copy a file and the file name already exists and you choose not to override the file, Windows Explorer uses a specific file rename algorithm, i.e. it tries to append something like "copy", if this file exists, it appends a number in brackets, which is then incremented, in case these file names also are already taken. Please note, that this is a simplified version of the algorithm. In reality it is more complex.

Since I do not want to reverse engineer this behavior, is there a c# .Net-Api available that gives me direct access to this behavior when copying or creating files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.

Point mostly being that this is absolutely not a windows standard behavior, but only done in the Explorer (i.e. it is this particular program that does that).

Answer (score 1):

As @TomTom said, no there isn't, but the Windows Explorer behaviour is easy to reproduce:

Given

```
var source = @"C:\Temp\Source.txt";
var targetFolder = @"C:\Temp\";
```

Then,

```
var targetName = Path.GetFileName(source);
var target = Path.Combine(targetFolder, targetName);
while (File.Exists(target)) {
    targetName = "Copy of "+ targetName;
    var target = Path.Combine(targetFolder, targetName);
}

File.Copy(source, target);
```

Or you can do a Mac like:

```
var targetName = Path.GetFileName(source);
for (int i = 0; i < MAX_TRIES; i++) {
    var idx = (i==0)?"":(" ("+i.ToString()+")");
    var target = Path.Combine(targetFolder, targetName+idx);
    if (!File.Exists(target)) break;
}
File.Copy(source, target);
```

Comment: I have seen different behaviors on different Windows versions/languages: 'Copy of {0}', 'Kopie van {0}', '{0} (1)', etc.

Comment: @MarkO Yes -- Caveat, the above is not localised.

Comment: I would recommend against using this pattern because the above code contains a race condition (on thread and process level) in between the calls to file.exists and file.copy. I would rather try-catch on File.Copy and based on the exception try again with a different file name. This would eliminate the race conditions.

Comment: True, but try/catch can end up with problems during low disk space and permissions issues. Using a mutex or similar would clutter the sample code.